# Parse Response string to Object in Angular2+

Tags: angular, angular-http, angular-httpclient

An API is responding json in string quotes 
How can I parse this to Object

```
"{"ErrorMessage":null,"UserBo":{"GateCollection":{"GateBosList":[]},"Status":0,"DlEd":"\/Date(1541278800000)\/","DlSd":"\/Date(1520715600000)\/","DlValue":"01:00","IsDl":true,"MobileIMEINo":null,"BranchId":0,"BranchName":null,"BUtcOffSt":"(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US \u0026 Canada)","UtcOffSt":"-8:0","IsDaylightSaving":false,"UserId":2031898,"CompanyId":3,"FirstName":"Yerandy","ChartCode":null,"LastName":null,"Email":null,"UserName":"YERANDY","Password":"123","WorkPhone":null,"WorkPhoneExt":null,"HomePhone":null,"CellNumber":null,"Fax":null,"DateCreated":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","LastLogin":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","IsAuthanticated":false,"IsSelected":false,"MobileUserStatus":null,"UserBosCollection":{"UserBosList":[]},"UserRoleBosCollection":{"RoleBosList":[{"CompanyId":3,"RoleId":6837,"Name":"Customer","Description":"Customer","CreatedBy":null,"Status":0,"ZonesList":{"ZoneBosList":[]},"UsersList":{"UserBosList":[]},"IsSelected":false},{"CompanyId":3,"RoleId":6838,"Name":"Carrier","Description":"Carrier","CreatedBy":null,"Status":0,"ZonesList":{"ZoneBosList":[]},"UsersList":{"UserBosList":[]},"IsSelected":false},{"CompanyId":3,"RoleId":2027893,"Name":"Order Entry","Description":"Order entry module","CreatedBy":"JAY","Status":0,"ZonesList":{"ZoneBosList":[]},"UsersList":{"UserBosList":[]},"IsSelected":false},{"CompanyId":3,"RoleId":2027898,"Name":"Dispatch \u0026 Order Entry","Description":"Dispatch \u0026 Order Entry","CreatedBy":"JAY","Status":0,"ZonesList":{"ZoneBosList":[]},"UsersList":{"UserBosList":[]},"IsSelected":false},{"CompanyId":3,"RoleId":2027899,"Name":"Order entry, Dispatch \u0026 Billin","Description":"Order entry, Dispatch \u0026 Billin","CreatedBy":"JAY","Status":0,"ZonesList":{"ZoneBosList":[]},"UsersList":{"UserBosList":[]},"IsSelected":false}]},"Company":{"CompanyLogo":null,"ReportLogo":null,"CompanyId":null,"IsQbposting":null,"IsEnableSsl":0,"IsUseDefaultCredentials":0,"SmtpPort":null,"SmtpHost":null,"InvoiceRemarks":null,"Name":null,"IsSelected":false,"DisplayName":null,"Description":null,"Status":0,"Res1":null,"Res2":null,"Res3":null,"CompanyCode":null,"Postal_Address":null,"Street_Address":null,"City":null,"State":null,"Zip":null,"Phone":null,"Fax":null,"Email":null,"Greetings":null,"FiscalYear":null,"TaxNo":null,"MasterUserName":null,"MasterUserPassword":null,"BranchesList":{"Branches":[]}},"CarrierId":null,"CustomerId":{"CustomerPdfBoList":null,"CustomerDocumentsBosList":null,"CustomerDocumentBo":null,"CustomerPhoneExt":null,"CustomerTypeBo":null,"CustomerService":null,"CustomerServiceList":null,"CompanyId":null,"IsSelected":false,"CustomerId":6484,"CustomerCode":null,"CustomerName":"YC INTERNATIONAL GROUP INC","CustomerType":0,"TradingPartner":null,"SynchronizationtypeId":null,"Phone":null,"Fax":null,"IsAutoFax":null,"Email":null,"CustomerBranchId":0,"CSR":null,"StartOfBusiness":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","Description":null,"Status":0,"PaymentTermId":0,"Res1":null,"Res2":null,"Res3":null,"Res4":null,"Res5":null,"CustomerSalesRep":null,"CustomerAddresses":{"AddressBosList":[]},"CustomerAddress":null,"CustomerContacts":{"ContactList":[]},"CustomerContact":null,"User":null,"CustomerTypeName":null,"CustomerPaymentTermsBo":null,"Site":null,"CustomerServiceCollection":null},"DeviceId":null,"Log":null,"UserImage":"Default.png","DispatchSettings":null},"AlertCount":0,"CacheContext":null,"DtoStatus":1,"Message":null,"CompanyId":null,"BranchId":null,"BaseFilterList":null,"StartDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","EndDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","Day":null}"
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` should do the trick. Give this a try:

```js
var stringResponse = '{"ErrorMessage":null,"UserBo":{"GateCollection":{"GateBosList":[]},"Status":0,"DlEd":"\/Date(1541278800000)\/","DlSd":"\/Date(1520715600000)\/","DlValue":"01:00","IsDl":true,"MobileIMEINo":null,"BranchId":0,"BranchName":null,"BUtcOffSt":"(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US \u0026 Canada)","UtcOffSt":"-8:0","IsDaylightSaving":false,"UserId":2031898,"CompanyId":3,"FirstName":"Yerandy","ChartCode":null,"LastName":null,"Email":null,"UserName":"YERANDY","Password":"123","WorkPhone":null,"WorkPhoneExt":null,"HomePhone":null,"CellNumber":null,"Fax":null,"DateCreated":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","LastLogin":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","IsAuthanticated":false,"IsSelected":false,"MobileUserStatus":null,"UserBosCollection":{"UserBosList":[]},"UserRoleBosCollection":{"RoleBosList":[{"CompanyId":3,"RoleId":6837,"Name":"Customer","Description":"Customer","CreatedBy":null,"Status":0,"ZonesList":{"ZoneBosList":[]},"UsersList":{"UserBosList":[]},"IsSelected":false},{"CompanyId":3,"RoleId":6838,"Name":"Carrier","Description":"Carrier","CreatedBy":null,"Status":0,"ZonesList":{"ZoneBosList":[]},"UsersList":{"UserBosList":[]},"IsSelected":false},{"CompanyId":3,"RoleId":2027893,"Name":"Order Entry","Description":"Order entry module","CreatedBy":"JAY","Status":0,"ZonesList":{"ZoneBosList":[]},"UsersList":{"UserBosList":[]},"IsSelected":false},{"CompanyId":3,"RoleId":2027898,"Name":"Dispatch \u0026 Order Entry","Description":"Dispatch \u0026 Order Entry","CreatedBy":"JAY","Status":0,"ZonesList":{"ZoneBosList":[]},"UsersList":{"UserBosList":[]},"IsSelected":false},{"CompanyId":3,"RoleId":2027899,"Name":"Order entry, Dispatch \u0026 Billin","Description":"Order entry, Dispatch \u0026 Billin","CreatedBy":"JAY","Status":0,"ZonesList":{"ZoneBosList":[]},"UsersList":{"UserBosList":[]},"IsSelected":false}]},"Company":{"CompanyLogo":null,"ReportLogo":null,"CompanyId":null,"IsQbposting":null,"IsEnableSsl":0,"IsUseDefaultCredentials":0,"SmtpPort":null,"SmtpHost":null,"InvoiceRemarks":null,"Name":null,"IsSelected":false,"DisplayName":null,"Description":null,"Status":0,"Res1":null,"Res2":null,"Res3":null,"CompanyCode":null,"Postal_Address":null,"Street_Address":null,"City":null,"State":null,"Zip":null,"Phone":null,"Fax":null,"Email":null,"Greetings":null,"FiscalYear":null,"TaxNo":null,"MasterUserName":null,"MasterUserPassword":null,"BranchesList":{"Branches":[]}},"CarrierId":null,"CustomerId":{"CustomerPdfBoList":null,"CustomerDocumentsBosList":null,"CustomerDocumentBo":null,"CustomerPhoneExt":null,"CustomerTypeBo":null,"CustomerService":null,"CustomerServiceList":null,"CompanyId":null,"IsSelected":false,"CustomerId":6484,"CustomerCode":null,"CustomerName":"YC INTERNATIONAL GROUP INC","CustomerType":0,"TradingPartner":null,"SynchronizationtypeId":null,"Phone":null,"Fax":null,"IsAutoFax":null,"Email":null,"CustomerBranchId":0,"CSR":null,"StartOfBusiness":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","Description":null,"Status":0,"PaymentTermId":0,"Res1":null,"Res2":null,"Res3":null,"Res4":null,"Res5":null,"CustomerSalesRep":null,"CustomerAddresses":{"AddressBosList":[]},"CustomerAddress":null,"CustomerContacts":{"ContactList":[]},"CustomerContact":null,"User":null,"CustomerTypeName":null,"CustomerPaymentTermsBo":null,"Site":null,"CustomerServiceCollection":null},"DeviceId":null,"Log":null,"UserImage":"Default.png","DispatchSettings":null},"AlertCount":0,"CacheContext":null,"DtoStatus":1,"Message":null,"CompanyId":null,"BranchId":null,"BaseFilterList":null,"StartDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","EndDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","Day":null}';

console.log(JSON.parse(stringResponse));
```